# Making an fs node

Tags: linux, kernel

I would like to create an fs node inside the linux file system to write to and read from. My goal is to write to this node from within the kernel when certain events occur and read the node from a userspace application.

I would like to write to the fs node from fork.c.Also, I would like to include this node under the /proc file system.

Can someone point me to the necessary functions in the kernel space that need to be used to create an fs node as  well as to the code files that are used to create the default file system structure?

Comment: What kind of FS node do you mean? A real file on disk, a device entry, a procfs entry…?

Comment: I would like a /procfs entry... essentially I want to have a hierarchy like this: /proc/mydirectory and subsequently /proc/mydirectory/field1 & /proc/mydirectory/field2 ... each of this fields will hold an integer